# Replacing key/value in NSDictionary

Tags: objective-c, nsdictionary, key-value

If I have a dictionary with the following key/value "foo"/"bar" and declared `[dictionary setObject:@"baz" forKey:@"foo"];` would this replace the current key value pair with "foo"/"baz" and delete "foo"/"bar"?

Comment: if you have a NSMutableDictionary, yep, it will replace the value (and release it).

Comment: Is it not practical for you to stick that line of code in a file and see what happens? That seems like a simple way to answer the question.

Comment: Try it and find out? My guess: It sets your box on fire and empties your bank account buying Twinkies. Gotta love the power of Cocoa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The behave of an **NSMutableDictionary** (as any common hash table) is that if it does not exists it creates a new key/value pair, if it already exits it will replace the existing value with the new one.

Answer (score 2):

The documentation here;

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40003692

suggests that it would. But please, don't take my word for it, read them yourself.

Perhaps you should also read;

http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Collections/Collections.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000034i